# Why does disposing of an entity context not free up memory

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, memory, glimpse

In my tests I am reading a text file line by line and inserting an entity along with other related entities. The problem is when too many are inserted I receive an Out of memory exception.

In my attempt to prevent this I create a new DbContext for every 50 rows and dispose of the old one. It was my understanding that this would free up memory from the earlier entity operations, but the memory continues to climb and if the file is big enough an out of memory exception occurs. This is related to the entity code as if I remove the lines of code that adds the entity the memory stays at a consistent usage.

Below is a simplified version of my code.

```
public class TestClass
{

  public void ImportData(byte[] fileBytes)
  {
    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
    {
        TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(stream);
        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        parser.SetDelimiters(",");

       while (!parser.EndOfData)
       {
          //Processes 50 lines creates a new DbContext each time its called
          ImportBatch(parser);          
       } 
    }
  }

  public void ImportBatch(TextFieldParser parser)
  {
    using(myDbContext context = new myDbContext())
    {
      context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

      int batchCount = 0;
      while (!parser.EndOfData && batchCount < 50)
      {
         string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

         //Here I call some code that will add an entity and add releated entities
         //In its navigation properties
         MyService.AddMyEntity(fields,myDbContext);

         batchCount++;
      } 

     myDbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
     myDbContext.SaveChanges();

    }
  }
}
```

As I am disposing and creating a new context every 50 inserts I would expect the memory usage to stay constant, but it seems to be constant for the first 2 thousands rows but after that the memory constantly climbs, unitl an OutOfMemory exception is hit.

Is there a reason why disposing of a dbContext in the following fashion would not result in the memory being released?

**EDIT - added some simplified code of my add entity method**

```
public void AddMyEntity(string[] fields, MyDbContext, myDbContext)
{
   MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
   newRequest.InsertDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
   newRequest.AmendDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

   //If I remove this line the memory does not consistently climb
   myDbContext.MyEntities.Add(myEntity);


   foreach(string item in fields)
   {
     ReleatedEntity releatedEntity = new ReleatedEntity();

     releatedEntity.Value = item;
     newRequest.ReleatedEntities.Add(releatedEntity);   
   }
}
```

**Another Edit**

Turns out after more testing it is something to do with Glimpse profiler. I have included Glimpse in my project and the web config has a section similar to below.

```
  <glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
<tabs>
  <ignoredTypes>
    <add type="Glimpse.Mvc.Tab.ModelBinding, Glimpse.Mvc5"/>
    <add type="Glimpse.Mvc.Tab.Metadata, Glimpse.Mvc5"/>

  </ignoredTypes>
</tabs>
<inspectors>
  <ignoredTypes>
    <add type="Glimpse.Mvc.Inspector.ModelBinderInspector, Glimpse.Mvc5"/>
  </ignoredTypes>
</inspectors>
```

Turning defaultRuntimePolicy to Off fixed the memory leak. Still not sure why tho

Comment: Aren't you adding the first 50 fields all the time?

Comment: @GregoryHouseMD Your right, my mistake, will edit. Either way this is just simplified code to demonstrate my issue

Comment: Just because you are disposing an object doesn't mean it's being garbage collected.  Are you running Visual Studio 2015?  If not, get the Community edition and debug with the profiler running.  You will see the garbage collection activity.  If you don't see any garbage collection then you may have to do some manual garbage collection at the end of your ImportBatch method.

Comment: Probably `MyService.AddMyEntity` leaks memory. Can you post the code of this method too?

Answer (score 2):

Calling `Dispose` on an object does not necessarily free up memory. Objects are removed from memory by the garbage collector when they are no longer referenced by any live object. Calling `Dispose` might free up other resources (e.g. by closing an open SQL connection in the case of a `DbContext`), but it's only when the object is no longer referenced that it becomes a candidate for garbage collection.

There's no guarantee that the garbage collector will run at a specific point in time. Calling `Dispose` certainly *doesn't* cause it to run. Having said that, I'm surprised that it doesn't run before you run out of memory. You could force it to run with `GC.Collect` but that really shouldn't be necessary.

It's possible that you still have a reference to your context objects that's causing them not to be considered eligible for garbage collection. For example, you pass `myDbContext` to your `AddEntity` method in your service layer - does that store something that includes a back-reference (even indirectly) to the context?

Answer (score 0):

Because whenever you call ImportBatch(parser) it creates a new DbContext. Not 1 DbContext for each 50. You may try a get property to count and give back the context to you. Something like this :

```
int _batchCount = 0;
public myDbContext _db;
public myDbContext Db
{
    get
    {
        // If batchCount > 50 or _db is not created we need to create _db
        if (_db == null || _batchCount > 50)
        {
            // If db is  already created _batchcount > 50
            if (_db != null)
            {
                _db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
                _db.SaveChanges();
                _db.Dispose();
            }

            _db = new myDbContext();
            _db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            _batchCount = 0;
        }
        batchCount++;
        return _db;
    }
}
```

Additionally in `MyService.AddMyEntity(fields);` you are using the DbContext from the `MyService`class, not the one you are creating in using line.

Comment: Why dispose of the context only to create another one right behind it?  That's no better than the original loop - you've just moved the reference to a class field.

Comment: Actually dispose of context creates another one beacuse it needs like so. Whenever newer one is called if _batchCount > 50 it creates another one and disposes old one. Thats what is trying to do there I think.